# Writing comments in metadata

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments, metadata, xml-comments

So I did some searching on google but did not find the answer or maybe did not understand the answer?

I would like to write some comments into my code so even after release it will be still visible in the metadata.[image: Example of some commenting in metadata]

Answer (score 1):

Surely, you can use treble slash `///` as it's a standard way to embed documentation into assembly code written in C#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Here is a newer article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/